# gruntjs / angularjs - optional development config?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, typescript

Like most js web apps we have a config.js file that contains global config information about the app, base api urls and such. These values are often different in local development than in production.

I've looked at answers like: [Development mode for AngularJS using GruntJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25507210/development-mode-for-angularjs-using-gruntjs), and also things like grunt-replace for creating an on-the-fly config file.

My issue is that the "development" part varies from developer to developer, we all need a version of the API setup so the base api urls will be different. I'd like to allow each developer to override specific variables in the config in a way that doesn't require them to commit that info to the git repo (I agree that this isn't best practice, everything should be in the repo, but as this is only 1/2 variables for this project I can overlook it)

Any ideas on how to achieve this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [grunt-preprocess](https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-preprocess). I would have production (and dev-server, etc) values in a file, say `env.json`. You could use grunt to look for an optional file, say `overrides.json` or `developer.json`, which would extend/overwrite the values from `env.json`.

```
var envFile = require('./env.json');
```

You can create command line options to grunt with `grunt.option`, e.g. `var env = grunt.option('env') || undefined;`, which could be used to turn off overriding.

You can get data from the optional file using `fs.existsSync`:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var developerFile;
if (fs.existsSync('./developer.json')) {
  developerFile = require('./developer.json');
}
```

The simplest way to define the grunt-preprocess context would be to use the `developer.json` file if present, or the `env.json` file if not:

```
context: developerFile ? developerFile : envFile;
```

This requires the developer file to be complete. An alternative is to extend the envFile with options from developerFile if it's present.

Comment: I like the sound of this. Could you expand on some of the details? How do you use grunt to look for an optional file? As that was something I couldn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

In my project, we use different config files (which are basically files with JS object). So every developer has his `app/configs/developer/config.js` file, which is not comited in the source control, so every developer has his own setup. Project uses link to `app/scripts/config.js` by default and this file is just a soft link to developers config file. However, there are also `app/configs/staging/config.js` and `app/configs/production/config.js` files, which are replaced when using gruntjj to build project. Those configs are just copied to build solution instead of soft linked file.

I hope that makes sense..